# onClick Label changes to text Input - then replace the initial label content with the user input content? [Quick Form Edit]

Tags: javascript, html, frontend

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".ProfileName").click(function () {
    var dad = $(this).parent().parent();
    dad.find("label").hide();
    dad.find('input[type="text"]').show().focus();
  });

  $("input[type=text]").focusout(function () {
    var dad = $(this).parent();
    $(this).hide();
    dad.find("label").show();
    document.getElementByClass(
      ".ProfileName"
    ).innerText = document.getElementByClass(".ProfileNameInput").innerText;
  });
});
```

```css
.ProfileNameInput {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="ProfileName" style="font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;font-size: 40px;" for="profileName" onclick="changeProfileName()">Jane M. Doe</label><input type="text" class="ProfileNameInput" style="width: 70%;" />
```

**What I want:**

I'm trying to make a user profile editing feature.
I want it to be quick and seamless, let's use the user's Full Name as an example:

label -> user clicks it -> label transforms to a text input -> user enters their name -> clicks out of the input -> input content replaces the label content.

Note: When the label get's clicked it's `display` is set to `:none`, and the input is set to `display: block` and `focused` to be able to show the label when the input is no longer in focus.

**My Progress:**

HTML

```
<label class="ProfileName" style="font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;font-size: 40px;" for="profileName" onclick="changeProfileName()">Jane M. Doe</label>

<input type="text" class="ProfileNameInput" style="width: 70%;" />
```

CSS

```
.ProfileNameInput {
  display: none;
}
```

JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.ProfileName').click(function () {
        var dad = $(this).parent().parent();
        dad.find('label').hide();
        dad.find('input[type="text"]').show().focus();
    });
    
    $('input[type=text]').focusout(function() {
        var dad = $(this).parent();
        $(this).hide();
        dad.find('label').show();
        document.getElementByClass(".ProfileName").innerText = document.getElementByClass(".ProfileNameInput").innerText;
    });
});
```

**My Question/Problem:**

The label content is not updating.

I tried using `.InnerHTML`, `.Value`, but nothing is working. I bet my JS syntax is wrong. But I can't figure it out.

Q1/ How can I update my label using JavaScript?
Q2/ Will there be any drawbacks to using this methods for updating my forms? Anything I'm unaware of that will be an issue later for this type of editing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better get tags by id, you taking `innerHTML` not input field `value` that is why you could not see input values

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".ProfileName").click(function () {
    var dad = $(this).parent().parent();
    dad.find("label").hide();
    dad.find('input[type="text"]').show().focus();
  });

  $("input[type=text]").focusout(function () {
    var dad = $(this).parent();
    $(this).hide();
    dad.find("label").show();
    document.getElementById(
      "ProfileName"
    ).innerText = document.getElementById("ProfileNameInput").value;
  });
});
```

```css
.ProfileNameInput {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="ProfileName" id="ProfileName" style="font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;font-size: 40px;" for="profileName">Jane M. Doe</label><input type="text" class="ProfileNameInput" id="ProfileNameInput" style="width: 70%;" />
```

Answering question 2 and 3: from ux side that is not intuitive but if you make it more obvious it could work

Comment: What do you mean by "js edits only for one browser session so that will ne removed on reload"

Do you mean that the edits will not be saved? I understand that and I will implement a way to send the data to be sent the servers and backend database. 

Is that what you meant?

Comment: Thank you its working. And for the UX, you are right. I'll inform the user ofc but that comes later. For now I need to get the functionalities working.